# showing app logo on toolbar

Tags: java, android

i want to put my logo an actionbar so i put an relativelayout inside toolbar which contain an image view but i got no result when its running.
(its not a icon ,so i cant use seticon() method )

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.655"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.307">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fragment"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.443"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

one more thing is i have set the resource in java file
and i got error whenever i use toollbar methods (seticon,setlogo...)

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: Just use the setLogo method on the toolbar with the resource id.

Answer (score 1):

Ok  You Have Options

1- use Toolbar with it`s material Design like this

[image]

then you need to use this code

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
 toolbar.setLogo(icon);
```

2- deal with Tool bar as A View  Just Like Any other View If you want to change position 
of the Image And texts

Comment: no i got error(usually this happen when i use toollbar methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom toolbar and add it into your activity

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
  getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_toolbar);
  Imageview mView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.title)
  mView.setImageResource(enter image here);
```